# style.marginLeft function is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a multi step user registration form using HTML. I have added two parts and now when I refer the next button from javascript, it works but comes back to first page after the transition.

HTML code:

```
            <form>
                <div class="page slidePage ">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="label">Username*</div>
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="label">Firstname*</div>
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="label">Lastname*</div>
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <button class="nxt nextBtn-1">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="page">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="label">Email</div>
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="label">Password</div>
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="label">Password Confirmation</div>
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field buttons">
                        <button class="prev-1 prev">Previous</button>
                        <button class="submit">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Javascript:

```
const slidePage = document.querySelector(".slidePage");
const first_nextBtn = document.querySelector(".nextBtn-1");
const first_prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev-1");

first_nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-25%";
});

first_prevBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    slidePage.style.marginLeft = "[enter link description here][1]0%";
});
```

But this is happening:
[1]: https://youtu.be/XSTL6Dpl42M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `<button>` in a form submit the form and reload the page

use `<button type="button">` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use prevent default. It stops the page for reloading.

```
first_nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    slidePage.style.marginLeft = "-25%";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The form refresh the page, you can use

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

Or use event.preventDefault()